# Can't add MySQL database to ClearDB, -u command not found

Tags: mysql, heroku, cleardb

Doing the following, I am unable to import a MySQL database to ClearDB:

```
$mysql -u b4587523b48993 -h us-cdbr-iron-east-05.cleardb.net -p heroku_571df93b7623da9 < ./sql/sql_import.php
```

Whenever I try I get the error

```
-u: command not found
```

If I put `sudo` in front it says:

```
sudo: unknown user: b4587523b48993
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like `mysql` isn't part of the command you're running. Is your prompt `$`, `$mysql`, or something else?

Comment: @Chris it's $mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Before doing anything else**, please invalidate those connection credentials and generate new ones. They're forever compromised.*

The entire command you're running, from `-u` to the end, should be arguments to the `mysql` command. Your `$mysql` shell prompt may make it look like that's what you're doing, but it isn't.

Add `mysql` to the beginning of your command (and adjust to account for your new credentials):

```
$mysql mysql -u b4587523b48993 -h us-cdbr-iron-east-05.cleardb.net -p heroku_571df93b7623da9 < ./sql/sql_import.php
```

As a side note, it's probably a good idea to lose the habit of prefixing `sudo` to commands that don't work. It's fine to do this in some situations, but it's important to recognise them. It shouldn't be your default troubleshooting action.